# Swift -Add loading cell while paginating

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Right now I use the code at the bottom of this question to paginate and everything works fine but I would like to add a loading cell to the the collectionView once the paginating starts and remove it after the paginating stops.

I tried the following but it just adds the loading cell to the bottom of the cv and the loading cell never leaves.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return datasource.count + 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == tableData.count {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: loadingCell, for: indexPath) as! LoadingCell
        cell.spinner.startAnimating()
        return cell
    }

    return cell // this is a normal cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if indexPath.item == tableData.count {

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 40) // loading cell is 40 pts
    }

    return CGSize(width: width, height: 80) // normal cell is 80 pts
}
```

I also tried using sections but the same problem occured

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return datasource.count
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: loadingCell, for: indexPath) as! LoadingCell
        cell.spinner.startAnimating()
        return cell
    }

    return cell // this is a normal cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if indexPath.section == 1 {

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 40) // loading cell is 40 pts
    }

    return CGSize(width: width, height: 80) // normal cell is 80 pts
}
```

**How can I remove add and remove the loading cell only when handlePaginating() is called/finished?**

```
var startKey: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    handlePagination()
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height

    if maximumOffset - contentOffset <= 10 {

        handlePagination()
    }
}

func handlePagination() {

    if startKey == nil {

        Database...Ref?.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 10).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self](snapshot) in

            guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return}

            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    // append child to datasource
            }
            self?.startKey = children.key
        })

    } else {

        Database...Ref?.queryOrderedByKey().queryEnding(atValue: startKey!).queryLimited(toLast: 11).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self](snapshot) in

            guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return}

            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                // insert child in datasource at statIndex
            }
            self?.startKey = children.key
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Add one flag variable, when pagination method call make flag true and reload collectionview. after pagination complete make flag false, check this condition in `cellForItemAt ` and `numberOfItemsInSection `.

Comment: I actually tried that earlier and it didn’t work. Thanks though 

Comment: have you used with `willdisplaycell` method ?

Comment: I tired this, but it didn't work: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let lastElement = tableData.count - 1
        if indexPath.item == lastElement {
            handlePagination()
        }
    } I got it from another SO answer but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the idea of a flag property from @PratikPrajapati answer in conjunction with the first part of my question.

I declared a property and initially set it as `var isPaging = false`. Then inside`cellForItem` and `sizeForItem` I check to see if the bool value is either `true` or `false`.

Inside the `else` clause of `handlePagination()`, I set the flag to `isPaging = true` and then call `collectionView.reloadData()` so that when the cv is reloaded, `cellForItem` and `sizeForItem` will now show the spinner inside the loading cell and give it a height of 40.

Last inside the `else` clause's callback I set the flag back to `false` and call `collectionView.reloadData()` again so that all the cells are updated, the spinner is no longer spinning, and the loading cell’s size is `.zero`:

```
Database...Ref?.queryOrderedByKey() ....
    // callback
    self?.isPaging = false
    // ...
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        self?.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
...
```

Here is the complete code:

```
var isPaging = false
var startKey: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    handlePagination()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return datasource.count + 1 // *** make sure to add the + 1 to this ***
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == tableData.count {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: loadingCell, for: indexPath) as! LoadingCell

        if isPaging {
            cell.spinner.startAnimating()
        } else {
            cell.spinner.stopAnimating()
        }

        return cell
    }

    return cell // this is a normal cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if indexPath.item == tableData.count {

        if isPaging {
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 40) // if it's true then set the loading cell's size
        } else {
            return .zero // if it's false then set the loading cell's size to .zero
        }
    }

    return CGSize(width: width, height: 80) // normal cell is 80 pts
}

func handlePagination() {

    if startKey == nil {

        Database...Ref?.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 10).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self](snapshot) in

            guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return}

            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    // append child to datasource
            }
            self?.startKey = children.key
        })

    } else {

        isPaging = true
        collectionView.reloadData()
        // add a function to auto scroll to the last cell

        Database...Ref?.queryOrderedByKey().queryEnding(atValue: startKey!).queryLimited(toLast: 11).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self](snapshot) in

            self?.isPaging = false

            guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return}

            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                // insert child in datasource at statIndex
            }

            self?.startKey = children.key
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
               self?.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height

    if maximumOffset - contentOffset <= 10 {

        handlePagination()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one extra flag variable in current code to work properly. what happen in you current code is when last cell about to display it will call `handlePagination` then you add loading cell without any condition that `handlePagination` is currently in process. so after you add loading cell, `willDisplay` method call api again.

Hope this help.

E.G:

```
var isApiCalling = false

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
       let lastElement = tableData.count - 1 
       if indexPath.item == lastElement && !isApiCalling { 
              isApiCalling = true
              handlePagination() 
       } 
  }


func handlePagination() {
   //After you get response from API called. reset isApiCalling to false.
  isApiCalling  = false.
}
```

Comment: I couldn't your answer to work but your flag idea helped me figure out another way. Please take a look at my answer when you get a chance. Thanks for the help. Cheers :)